# On a proof that the harmonic series diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration, harmonic-numbers

I had a question on whether my proof that the harmonic series diverges or not; we wish to evaluate:
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
We will re-write the inner expression in the following fashion:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1}$$
We thus recignise that our suum $S$ is in fact equal to the following integral via the definition of Riemann integrals:
$$S=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\ dx$$
Which obviously diverges to $+\infty$.

Is this proof correct and rigorous? I got the idea from reading a book I recently got on how to succeed in a CPGE class and it provoked me too getting more creative with using Riemann integration.

Comment: I think technically speaking more work would be needed. Because $x\mapsto 1/x$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ we can't immediately say "Oh, the Riemann partial sums converge to the integral". We might like to say: "If the limit of the sums existed, then it would converge to the value of the integral which is $+\infty$, a contradiction" but I'm not sure how airtight it is, because the integral would be an *improper* Riemann integral anyway (integrating on $[\epsilon,1]$ and then trying to push that to $[0,1]$?)

Comment: "Obviously diverges..." Why? for example, $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\,dx$$ converges.

Comment: So, if you know the definite integral of $\int_t^1\frac1x\,dx,$ for $t>0,$ then you can argue it, but you put it under "Obviously."

Comment: Well it obviously diverges as it is equal to $\lim_{n\to0}(ln(1)-ln(n))=+\infty$

Comment: The "Riemann sum" converging to the integral is only known for Riemann integrable functions.  Note that $1/x$ is not Riemann integrable on interval  $(0,1)$.  So you need more reasoning here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not work because the theorem on convergence on Riemann sums requires $f$ to be continuous on a segment $[a,b]$, in your case you applied it to $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ on $[0,1]$ which is not correct. Here is a way to correct your reasoning : let $\delta\in]0,1[$, on the one hand
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\geqslant\delta n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1}\chi_{[\delta,1]}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}\longrightarrow\int_{\delta}^1\frac{dx}{x}=-\log\delta. $$
On the other hand,
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\leqslant\delta n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1}\geqslant\frac{\lfloor\delta n\rfloor}{\delta n}. $$
Therefore, if $\delta$ is fixed, we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\geqslant -\log\delta $$
for all $n$ large enough but since $\lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\log\delta=-\infty$, $-\log\delta$ can be taken as large as you want which means that the harmonic series diverges.